# Error using getNOAA.bathy, are there restrictions on coordinates values?

Tags: r

I am trying to execute `getNOAA.bathy` from package `marmap`.

I can **successfully** execute the following (from [here](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/marmap/docs/getNOAA.bathy)):

```
library(marmap)
getNOAA.bathy(lon1=-20,lon2=-90,lat1=50,lat2=20, resolution=10) -> a
plot(a, image=TRUE, deep=-6000, shallow=0, step=1000)
```

However, when I execute the following:

```
getNOAA.bathy(lon1=-80,lon2=-79.833333,lat1=32.7,lat2=32.833333, resolution=10) -> a
plot(a, image=TRUE, deep=-6000, shallow=0, step=1000)
```

**I get the error:**

> Error in getNOAA.bathy(lon1 = -80, lon2 = -79.833333, lat1 = 32.7, lat2 = 32.833333,  : The NOAA server cannot be reached

### Questions:

- Are there special restrictions to LAT/LON values? Am I
  miscalculating something here?
- Are there "better" packages that can support my LAT/LON values?

Comment: Which package are you talking about?

Comment: @Pascal: I belieave it is [marmap](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/marmap/docs/getNOAA.bathy)

Comment: I guess your region is too small for the data set resolution.

Comment: @Pascal: It can execute when resolution is <=5.. but that resolution is useless. what do you advise?

Comment: You cannot change the resolution of the data set. Extend your region.

Comment: @Pascal: I am interested in a very small region but high zoom rate, is that possible?

Comment: I didn't notice the argument `resolution = 10` in your try. You need to remove it. With `getNOAA.bathy(lon1=-80, lon2= 79.833333, lat1=32.7, lat2=32.833333)`, you get 6 points.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in the help file for `getNOAA.bathy()`, the `resolution` argument is expressed in minutes. So `resolution=10` means that the cells of your grid will have a dimension of 10 minutes in longitude by 10 minutes in latitude. The bigger the number, the worse the resolution. So considering your region, you need to use the highest resolution possible for the ETOPO1 dataset (i.e. the database that's fetched by `getNOAA.bathy()`):

```
getNOAA.bathy(lon1=-80, lon2= 79.833333, lat1=32.7, lat2=32.833333, res=1)
```

That's definitely not hi-res (you get a grid of 80 values: 10 latitude values by 8 longitude values), but that's the maximum you can get with `getNOAA.bathy()`.

If you need a higher resolution, you should try other sources such as the [GEBCO database](http://www.gebco.net) and the `readGEBCO()` function of `marmap`. You should also have a look at sections 2 and 3 of the `marmap-ImportExport` vignette where other sources are listed.

```
vignette("marmap-ImportExport")
```